# Call Web APi from MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-web-api, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have created **Web API** using `Oracle Database` in C# ASP.NET MVC and `ADO.NET Entity Model` and everything works fine. 
And right now, I need to create a another project which will call this API. 
I create this because this Web API is a part of application and it will connect to another application. 
I create a new MVC project and in my controller

```
 public ActionResult GetAkontas()
        {
            IEnumerable<AkontasViewModel> akontas = null;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57285/api/");


               var responseTask = client.GetAsync("akontas");
               responseTask.Wait();
               var result = responseTask.Result;

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = GetReadTask(result);
                    readTask.Wait();

                    akontas = readTask.Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Error response received   
                    akontas = Enumerable.Empty<AkontasViewModel>();
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error try after some time.");
                }
            }
            return View(akontas);

        }
```

Here is the problem that I dont know how to call it API controller, do I need to have connection to server since I work with Oracle database ?

I create Model but not so sure do I need it however

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AkontasMVCWebApi.Models
{
    public class AkontasViewModel
    {
        public string A_KONTO { get; set; }
        public string NAZIV { get; set; }
        public string SIFRA_RAD { get; set; }
        public string OPSTINA { get; set; }
        public string MB { get; set; }
        public string ULICA { get; set; }
        public string BROJ { get; set; }
        public string PBROJ { get; set; }
        public string MJESTO { get; set; }
        public string PORESKI { get; set; }
        public string TRANSAKCIJ { get; set; }
        public string INTERNET { get; set; }
        public string EMAIL { get; set; }
        public string KONTAKT { get; set; }
        public string TELEFON { get; set; }
        public string FAKS { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DAT_UNOS { get; set; }
        public string PDVMB { get; set; }
        public string VRSTA_KLIJENTA { get; set; }
        public string DRZAVA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my first time to work with Oracle database and ADO.NET Entities and not so sure how to do this, create a Project which will call(use) my `API`

**UPDATE**

Here is my Web API project

**Controller**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace AkontasWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class AkontasController : ApiController
    {
        //Ovo je objekat kojem se pristupa kroz bazu
        public AkontasEntities db = new AkontasEntities();

        // GET: api/Akontas
        //Ovo je funkcija koja vraca Listu<> svih AKONTASA iz baze ne vezano po ID-u
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Akontas")]
        public IQueryable<AKONTA> GetAKONTAS()
        {
            return db.AKONTAS;
        }

        // GET: api/Akontas/5 -> ovo je routing tacnije putanja kako se koristi ova funkcija           
        //Ovo je funkcija koja vraca AKONTAS po ID-u 
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(AKONTA))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAKONTA(string id)
        {
            AKONTA aKONTA = db.AKONTAS.Find(id);
            if (aKONTA == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Ne postoji A_KONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }

            return Ok(aKONTA);
        }

    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
<br /><br />
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A_KONTO</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO" id='AkontasId'>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto" onClick='aKontoSubmit()'>Provjeri</a>
    </div>
</form>


<script>       
    function aKontoSubmit() {

        $.ajax({          
            type: "GET",            
            URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",
            data: { id: $('#AkontasId').val() },
            contentType: "data/xml; charset=utf-8",  
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is the code you showed is from you MVC project or from your Web API project?

Comment: From my MVC project

Comment: Sorry I will add my Web API project code also. I forget it

Comment: Then I have another question; What exactly is your problem? Is the API not returning data, or is the Status Code from `client.GetAsync(...)` never a Success status code...

Comment: No, I just not getting data. Browser is runnig but I didnt get any result

Comment: Ok, then try this: Make sure your Web API is running and has a visual studio instance debugging it. Then place a breakpoint on the line `return db.AKONTAS` in your Web API. Now start your MVC project (with the API still running and still being debugged) and place a breakpoint on the line `var result = responseTask.Result;` and then execute the method `GetAtonkas()`. What should happen is that the Web API breakpoint will be hit, once it hits press continue in VS, then the MVC Projects breakpoint will be hit, here you can now look at `result` and see what happened

Comment: SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 130. Expecting element 'ArrayOfAkontasViewModel' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AkontasMVCWebApi.Models'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'ArrayOfAKONTA', namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AkontasWebApi'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199502/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-xerror).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend some stuff to look out for:

1) Try using `https` in `http://localhost:57285/api/`. I've had a similar problem but not on IIS, I was using kestrel web server.

2) Try this after setting the base address and before `GetAsync()`:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

//Define request data format    
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```